# Why would area under the PR curve include points off of the Pareto front?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, auc, precision-recall

(Let's set aside thoughts about if we should be calculating PR curves or areas under them at all.)

A precision-recall curve for a "classification" model can contain points that should not be taken seriously. That is, there can be a point $(r_0, p_0)$ such that some other point on the curve $(r_1, p_1)$ has $r_1\ge r_0$, $p_1\ge p_0$, and at least one strict equality. Why would we take a point that does worse in both measures of performance?

As far as I can tell, when the area under the PR curve is calculated, these points are considered.

Would it be better to calculate the area under the Pareto front of the PR curve that discards these points? The Pareto front is the set $\left\{(r, p)\in\{\text{PR Curve}\}\subset [0,1]^2\big\vert \nexists(r^{\prime},p^{\prime})\in\{\text{PR Curve}\}\subset [0,1]^2 \space \text{ s.t. }\space r^{\prime}>r, p^{\prime}\ge p\space\text{ or }\space p^{\prime}>p, r^{\prime}\ge r\right\}$: the set of points on the PR curve such that no other point has better precision and recall (with one of those allowed to be weak inequality).